# Traefik 2.0 redirect

Tags: traefik

I would like to create a traefik v2 config file which redirects http://localhost:80 traffic to http://otherhost.example.com:8080.

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

[entryPoints]
   [entryPoints.dashboard]
   address = ":80"
   [entryPoints.dashboard.redirect???]
     scheme = "http"       
     port = "8080"
```

No dockers whatsoever.

Thanks,
Lorand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That worked:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]

## Static configuration
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

[providers]
  [providers.file]
    filename = "dynamic_conf.toml"
    watch = true
```

And `dynamic_conf.toml`:

```
## Dynamic configuration

[http.routers]
  [http.routers.Router-1]
    # By default, routers listen to every entry points
    rule = "Host(`localhost`)"
    service = "my-service"

[http.services]
  [http.services.my-service.loadBalancer]
    passHostHeader = false
    [[http.services.my-service.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://example.com"
```

It had to be called with full url, like: http://localhost/index.html